# How can I break up Lambda expression into the objects that make up the expression?

Tags: lambda, expression, modelmetadata

Given an expression such as:

**m => m.Employee.Address.Line1**

I need to create a function that can walk the expression, pulling out the objects involved, or AT LEAST the final object in the chain (i.e. the Address object above). So for the example above, the function will find:

- "here" is the instance of the m parameter (from which I can get the type)
- "here" is the instance of the Employee member
- (i.e. repeat down the chain)

The intent is to be able to generate configuration information for the "path".

If I can at least get the final "containing" object, then I can produce type information, as well as call into the object if it supports specific attributes or methods, to request additional configuration information from the object (and the object Type to obtain configuration information for the Type of the container).

Even slightly more complex statements make this even harder, such as:

**m.Employee.Address[i].Line1**

--- Just to provide a sample of what I do have working for a BASIC scenario in MVC. The below GetContainingModel() is called inside a CreateMetadata() in the loaded DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider.  The Model that is passed into CreateMetadata() is the model at the ROOT of the Lambda statement, not really what we want.  So the logic attempts to find the final containing object.  I'd prefer to NOT use reflection as I'm doing or worse, reaching in to get a private member (bad), but... I'm up for suggestions.

```
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    private object GetContainingModel()
    {
        if (_metadata == null)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Unexpected NULL Metadata");
        }

        var model = _metadata.Model;

        try
        {
            if (_modelAccessor != null)
            {
                var data = _modelAccessor.Target;
                if (data != null)
                {
                    if (GetModelFromContainer(data, ref model))
                    {
                        GetModelFromExpression(data, ref model);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }

        return model;
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    private bool GetModelFromContainer(object data, ref object model)
    {
        var isSet = false;

        var container = data.GetType().GetField("container");
        if (container != null)
        {
            model = container.GetValue(data);
            isSet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var vdi = data.GetType().GetField("vdi");
            if (vdi != null)
            {
                var viewDataInfo = vdi.GetValue(data) as ViewDataInfo;
                if (viewDataInfo != null)
                {
                    model = viewDataInfo.Container;
                    isSet = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return isSet && model != null;
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    private bool GetModelFromExpression(object data, ref object model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            return false;

        var expressionField = data.GetType().GetField("expression");
        if (expressionField == null)
            return false;

        return GetModelFromExpression(expressionField.GetValue(data) as LambdaExpression, ref model);
    }

    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    private bool GetModelFromExpression(LambdaExpression sourceExpression, ref object model)
    {
        if (sourceExpression == null)
            return false;

        var expressionBody = sourceExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (expressionBody == null || expressionBody.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess || expressionBody.Member == null)
            return false;


        var expression = expressionBody.Expression as MemberExpression;
        if (expression == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        switch (expression.Member.MemberType)
        {
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                {
                    var fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)expression.Member;
                    if (fieldInfo != null)
                    {
                        model = fieldInfo.GetValue(model);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)expression.Member;
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    model = propertyInfo.GetValue(model, null);
                }
                break;
        }

        return model != null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this yet? It would be useful to post where you're at with it

Comment: Not yet.  Thanks! including the interest.  If I find any info I'll make sure I update the post.